# Gap between two html sections

Tags: html, css, web, brackets

As you can see in the pictures, i have those two gaps between those sections (white space). I tried doing the `padding/margin : 0;` method, but it didn't work.

Any other possible solution?

EDIT: The problem was margin between two sections.

Screenshots showing the problem:

**Screenshot sample 1**
[image: Screenshot sample 1]

**Screenshot sample 2 - Marked with red overlay**
[image: Screenshot sample 2 - Marked with red overlay]

Comment: Give us your code, please.

Comment: https://codepen.io/AndreasDEV/pen/MXRRLo

For some kind of a reason, preview is not working properly on codepen.

Comment: Codepen is not working because you put HTML into the CSS container

Comment: I did, forgot to save it. Its still not working as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your css:

```
ul{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```